# How do you configure a MessageInspector when using StandardEndpoints in WCF REST 4.0

Tags: wcf, message, behavior, inspector

I'm trying create and configure a Message Inspector to perform some authentication of a WCF Rest HTTP request. I'm using 4.0 so trying to steer clear of the WCF Starter Kit although I have managed to get an old RequestInterceptor working in the way I want. The problem with using RequestInterceptor is that I lost the automaticFormatSelectionEnabled features provided by WebHttpBehavior which I really want to keep.

So my question is how do I configure the Message Inspector in a way that I still use the WebHttpBehavior and keep it's features.

My web.config looks like this

```
    <standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <!-- the "" standard endpoint is used by WebServiceHost for auto creating a web endpoint. -->
    <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
    <!-- Disable the help page for the directory end point-->
    <standardEndpoint name="DirectoryEndpoint"/>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

Answer (score 20):

One way you can handle this is to create three objects.

1. The message inspector, responsible for analyzing the
   request/response
2. The service behavior, automatically injects the inspector into the
   pipeline
3. The configuration section, allows the behavior to be used in the
   web.config

First create the message inspector by implementing IDispatchMessageInspector
 and putting your validation code in the AfterReceiveRequest method:

```
public class HmacVerificationInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{

    #region IDispatchMessageInspector Members

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, 
        System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
            MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            request = buffer.CreateMessage();
            Message dupeRequest = buffer.CreateMessage();

            ValidateHmac(dupeRequest);

            buffer.Close();

        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, 
        object correlationState)
    {


    }

    #endregion
}
```

It's important to create a buffered copy of the message when reading it. Messages can only be opened once and not creating a copy will lead to problems down the pipe. My implementation of ValidateHmac throws an exception if it fails. This prevents the actual service from being called.

Second, create a behavior for your inspector. We'll use the behavior to inject the inspector into the WCF runtime. To create the behavior, derive a class from IEndpointBehavior so it looks like this

```
 public class HmacVerificationBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        #region IEndpointBehavior Members

        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            HmacVerificationInspector inspector = new HmacVerificationInspector();

            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {

        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Notice I create a new instance of my inspector (`HmacVerificationInspector`) and inject it programmatically into the runtime.

Finally, the last step is to create a configuration section. We can use this to apply the behavior in the web config (thus being able to turn it on and off via configuration). Create a new class and inherit from BehaviorExtensionElement and IServiceBehavior:

```
public class HmacVerificationConfigurationSection : BehaviorExtensionElement, IServiceBehavior
{
    #region IServiceBehavior Members

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, 
        System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, 
        System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, 
        System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {

    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {

    }

    #endregion

    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof(HmacVerificationBehavior); }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new HmacVerificationBehavior();
    }
}
```

Now, to use the inspector, add the following to your web.config (you can set the name for your extension to whatever you want)

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="hmacVerification" type="NamespaceHere.HmacVerificationConfigurationSection, AssembleyHere, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <services>
            <service name="MySecureService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMySecureService" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />          
                    <hmacVerification />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Couple of things, first you register the configuration section in the behavior extensions. Next, you use that configuration as an endpoint behavior which will then automatically inject the inspector and all requests to that endpoint will run through your inspector. If you want to turn off the inspector, remove the  tag or select a different endpoint behavior. Note the use of the webHttp behavior also (which will allow you to keep automaticFormatSelectionEnabled.

Hope this helps

Comment: You know I think this might be outdated.

Comment: On the contrary I think its very much helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Better post about wcf message I've read in a lot of time. Thank you very much.